# Add event in iPhone/Android Calendar with PhoneGap/Telerik Appbuilder Hybrid Apps?

Tags: jquery, kendo-mobile, telerik-appbuilder

I am working on telerik appbuilder hybrid app. I want to add event from my app to iPhone/Android Calendar.
But i didn't found any solution how to implement this functionality.

Please help me and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at this Cordova [Calendar plugin](http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/calendar) from the Verified Plugins Marketplace.